# Ubuntu karmic rhythmbox and nautilus integation - open with rhythmbox takes two tries to work

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, nautilus, rhythmbox

The Open With Rhythmbox right click context menu option in Nautilus for mp3 files isn't working properly.  On the first selection of the context menu item it starts up rhythmbox if it isn't already running or stops what is playing if it is but it doesn't start playing the selected file.

On the second try it works.

Is there anything I can do to fix this relatively minor annoyance?

Comment: did you try reinstall it?

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the setup described in this article :
[Queue music into Rhythmbox from Nautilus](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/26/queue-music-into-rhythmbox-from-nautilus/).